# Why am I not getting equal squares when I unwrap?

Tags: uv

I'm making a pillow and I have marked a seam in the center. When I unwrap with pressing U, instead of getting squares I'm getting a different result.

[image]

This is the uv result:

[image]

I tried smart uv

[image]

Why am I not getting just to equal squares? Any suggestion or Help

[image]

Comment: Try going into top view and project form view. Also, remember to **Apply** the scale to your object in object mode before unwrapping.

Comment: @cegaton wow it work but may i know reason why with the normal unwrap it did not work with so simple geometry. And plz post as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you had "Pinned" parts of the UV's. I removed the pinned UVs in the UV Editor <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to Un-Pin. And in object mode as a matter of habit applied scale and rotation <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then back in the UV Editor keeping the seam you created unwrapped Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select "Unwrap" from the drop down menu.

[image: unwrapping in Blender]